# Webflux async requests showing up as different traceIds in datadog

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, datadog

We are using datadog in our webflux application, and the spans are showing as expected. However, they're not in 1 specific resource traceId, but rather broken down into different traceIds. I want to have 1 traceId that contains all of these async requests as spans.

Example code:

```
return someRepository.find(req.body().item())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(ExampleCodeException::new))
        .map(FooService)
        .flatMap(email -> DoSomethingService(email))
        ...
```

This will have 2 traceIds for each async request instead of 1 main traceId with all the spans inside.